# Laravel 5: Heavy Select Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, innodb, laravel-5

I have about 25.000 rows in my DB table 'movies' (InnoDB, 17.5 mb)
And when I try to get them all to display in my admin panel, nothing happens. Just 5-8 seconds pending and white screen. No displayed errors, just nothing. (max execution time is 3600 seconds, because it's on my local machine). My simple as hell code:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['movies'] = Movies::all();

    dd('This var_dump & die never fires');

    // return view('admin.movies', $data);
}
```

I just wonder why it not performs the query and just die without declaration of war.

I didn't found anything interesting in .ENV or config/database.php to explain what happens in such situations.

PS. yes, I can make serverside pagination and search, and take only 10-25 records from the DB, question is not about that.

Comment: If you try to load 25k records at once, all bets are off - let alone creating Eloquent objects for each one of them.

Comment: Is PHP involved?  For some forms of data, the expansion factor is 40x.  If that applies in your case, that blows up to nearly a gigabyte.

Comment: Did you expected that browser can handle such data, not that server spits data in a first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are running out of memory. Try quering half, of the results, or maybe just 100 to see if that at least fixes the white page, if so use chunk:

```
Movies::chunk(200, function($movies)
{
    foreach($movies $movie)
    {
        var_dump($movie);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely look at your `storage\logs` directory to verify the error. It's quite possible that it takes to much memory getting 25k rows.

In fact as you mentioned in real life there is no need to get so many rows because unless you export them into CSV or XLS.